# How to sort products by average rating from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to databases, so I haven't wrapped my head around how to use joins, subqueries etc. properly. That's why I'm very unsure how to go about sorting products by the average of another table.

Here's my usecase:

I have a straightforward products table in this style

```
|id|product|more fields|
|1 |hat    |feathered  |
|2 |pants  |jeans      |
|3 |pants  |cargo      |
```

And in a second table, produtcs_rating, I have the five-star ratings like

```
|id|product_id|rating|
|1 |    1     |   5  |
|2 |    2     |   2  |
|3 |    3     |   4  |
|4 |    1     |   4  |
|5 |    3     |   3  |
```

Now I want to be able to sort these on the website according to the average rating (simple arithmetic mean is fine).
Would something like this be working?

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY (SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating FROM product_ratings) DESC;
```

Or is this something where I should use a join? And if, how?
Any help for a beginner would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `products` to a query that returns the average ratings:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, AVG(rating) avg_rating
  FROM product_ratings 
  GROUP BY product_id
) r ON r.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY r.avg_rating DESC;
```

Or use a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
ORDER BY (SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating FROM product_ratings WHERE product_id = p.id) DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a5c348230124be6303370ea20fcb9e8e).
Results:

```
> id | product | more fields
> -: | :------ | :----------
>  1 | hat     | feathered  
>  3 | pants   | cargo      
>  2 | pants   | jeans
```

Comment: Thank you! From what I gather, joins are slightly faster but as the subquery version is far mor readable for me, I'll use that one and switch to joins should I ever run into performance problems. Side question: what exactly does the p. mean you've put before the *? Further down it's an alias for products, I believe, but right at the start?

Comment: p.* means all the columns of table p (= products).

Comment: Oh, so you can use the appreviation already after SELECT even though you define later after FROM. Interesting.

Comment: Aliases of tables are defined after FROM or JOIN and can be used in the SELECT list or in correlated subqueries like the 2nd query in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You  need  a join

```
    SELECT distinct p.* 
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN product_ratings r ON r.product_id = p.id
    ORDER BY r.rating DESC;
```